# How do you find an attacker if he immediately cleans after himself?

Tags: forensics, logging, system-compromise

Having an Ubuntu server with current software, updated daily, every 5 days or so someone gains root access. I know that from log watch.

I search the logs for his ip and it doesn't show up.

He is probably using a VPN as once it's in china, then Athens, then Russia.

Even if I send the logs every 10 minutes to another server, full hacks happen in seconds.

How do you find an attacker and his entry point if he immediately cleans after himself?

EDIT:

authorized keys

```
### /home/user:
ssh-rsa AAAABstring name@name2
ssh-rsa AAAABstring2 name@name2
ssh-rsa AAAABstring3 name@name2

### /root:
ssh-ed25519 AAAACstring UbuntuS
### /var/www/someurl:
ssh-rsa AAAABstring root@server.net
```

Excerpt:

```
 ################### Logwatch 7.4.3 (12/07/16) #################### 
        Processing Initiated: Mon Sep 28 04:27:04 2020
        Date Range Processed: yesterday
                              ( 2020-Sep-27 )
                              Period is day.
        Detail Level of Output: 0
        Type of Output/Format: mail / text
 ################################################################## 
 --------------------- Dovecot Begin ------------------------ 

 
 Dovecot IMAP and POP3 Successful Logins: 112
 
 Dovecot disconnects: 12 Total
 
 **Unmatched Entries**
    dovecot: service=imap, user=mail@mail.com, ip=[52.125.141.103]. Logged out rcvd=1005, sent=13729: 1 Time(s)
    dovecot: service=imap, user=mail@mail.com, ip=[52.125.141.103]. Logged out rcvd=1065, sent=13948: 1 Time(s)
    dovecot: service=imap, user=mail@mail.com, ip=[52.125.141.103]. Logged out rcvd=1137, sent=14250: 1 Time(s)
    dovecot: service=imap, user=mail@mail.com, ip=[52.125.141.103]. Logged out rcvd=1240, sent=6109: 1 Time(s)
    dovecot: service=imap, user=mail@mail.com, ip=[52.125.141.103]. Logged out rcvd=1253, sent=6167: 1 Time(s)
...
    dovecot: service=imap, user=mail@mail.com, ip=[78.48.143.126]. Logged out rcvd=223, sent=28426: 1 Time(s)
    dovecot: service=imap, user=mail@mail.com, ip=[78.48.143.126]. Logged out rcvd=223, sent=28434: 1 Time(s)
    dovecot: service=imap, user=mail@mail.com, ip=[78.48.143.126]. Logged out rcvd=847, sent=2010: 1 Time(s)
    dovecot: service=imap, user=mail@mail.com, ip=[78.63.130.44]. Logged out rcvd=1302, sent=4116: 1 Time(s)
    dovecot: service=imap, user=mail@mail.com, ip=[78.63.130.44]. Logged out rcvd=1307, sent=68773: 1 Time(s)
    dovecot: service=imap, user=mail@mail.com, ip=[78.63.130.44]. Logged out rcvd=175, sent=1164: 1 Time(s)
...

 
 --------------------- httpd Begin ------------------------ 

 
 A total of 9 sites probed the server 
    114.119.128.67
    139.192.20.154
    184.97.41.109
    189.238.82.255
    40.77.191.185
    78.63.130.44
 
 Requests with error response codes
    400 Bad Request
       /: 1 Time(s)
       /HNAP1/: 1 Time(s)
       /w00tw00t.at.ISC.SANS.DFind:): 1 Time(s)
       /wp-config.php#: 1 Time(s)
       /wp-config.php.#: 1 Time(s)
    404 Not Found
       /robots.txt: 33 Time(s)
       /FPURL.xml: 9 Time(s)
       /sitemap.xml: 4 Time(s)
       /vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php: 4 Time(s)
       /.env: 3 Time(s)
       /admin//config.php: 3 Time(s)
       /modules/base/js/owa.tracker-combined-min.js: 3 Time(s)
       /admin/.env: 2 Time(s)
       /administrator/.env: 2 Time(s)
       /api/jsonws/invoke: 2 Time(s)
       /app/.env: 2 Time(s)
       /apps/.env: 2 Time(s)
       /config/.env: 2 Time(s)
       /core/.env: 2 Time(s)
       /cron/.env: 2 Time(s)
       /database/.env: 2 Time(s)
       /index.php?id=1631: 2 Time(s)
       /index.php?id=1845: 2 Time(s)
       /index.php?id=2186: 2 Time(s)
       /index.php?id=2242: 2 Time(s)
       /index.php?id=2274: 2 Time(s)
       /index.php?id=2328: 2 Time(s)
       /index.php?id=3812': 2 Time(s)
       /index.php?id=867: 2 Time(s)
       /hudson: 1 Time(s)
       /index.php?id=1007: 1 Time(s)
       /index.php?id=1029: 1 Time(s)
       /index.php?id=1041: 1 Time(s)
...
       /m/index.php?id=12: 1 Time(s)
       /m/index.php?id=171: 1 Time(s)
       /m/index.php?id=184: 1 Time(s)
       /m/index.php?id=2120: 1 Time(s)
       /m/index.php?id=32: 1 Time(s)
       /m/index.php?id=3431: 1 Time(s)
...
       /mobile/index.php?id=1026: 1 Time(s)
       /mobile/index.php?id=1233: 1 Time(s)
...
       /portal/redlion: 1 Time(s)
       /setup.cgi?next_file=netgear.cfg&todo=sysc ... ntsetting.htm=1: 1 Time(s)
       /sitemap.xml.gz: 1 Time(s)
    408 Request Timeout
       null: 25 Time(s)
       /HNAP1/: 1 Time(s)
 
 ---------------------- httpd End ------------------------- 

 
 --------------------- HTTPD Errors Begin ------------------------ 

 
 Level alert :      4 Time(s)
 Level crit  :   1097 Time(s) 
 ---------------------- HTTPD Errors End ------------------------- 

 
 --------------------- pam_unix Begin ------------------------ 

 proftpd:
    Authentication Failures:
       www-data (62.103.225.208): 62 Time(s)
 
 
 ---------------------- pam_unix End ------------------------- 

 
 --------------------- proftpd-messages Begin ------------------------ 

 
 **Unmatched Entries**
 0.0.0.0 (62.103.225.208[62.103.225.208]) - SECURITY VIOLATION: Root login attempted
 0.0.0.0 (62.103.225.208[62.103.225.208]) - SECURITY VIOLATION: Root login attempted
 0.0.0.0 (62.103.225.208[62.103.225.208]) - SECURITY VIOLATION: Root login attempted
 0.0.0.0 (62.103.225.208[62.103.225.208]) - SECURITY VIOLATION: Root login attempted
...
 
 ---------------------- proftpd-messages End ------------------------- 

 
 ###################### Logwatch End #########################
```

Comment: The scenario doesn't make sense. If you have the logs that show you that they gained access, then you use those logs to do your investigation.

Comment: And why use a 10 minute window to copy logs over? Why not stream them?

Comment: How do you stream logs to a server?

Comment: From your previous question, `syslog` was mentioned. And in this question, you reference sending logs every 10 minutes. Are you not using syslog? How are you sending the logs?

Comment: Not related to the question, but if *the full hack happen in seconds*, I'm willing to bet good money that the first time the guy left behind some kind of backdoor. Automated backdoors are, nine times out of ten, just a .authorized_keys entry or a shell on some unused port. You can easily verify both possibilities.

Comment: Has your root password been [*pwned*](https://haveibeenpwned.com/Passwords)?

Comment: @vidarlo I edited the main post. It says "SECURITY VIOLATION: Root login attempted". According to http://www.proftpd.org/docs/modules/mod_auth.html `If a client attempts to login as root, using the correct password, a special security message is logged: SECURITY VIOLATION: Root login attempted`.

Comment: @usr-local-ΕΨΗΕΛΩΝ It hasn't. I checked my previous ones.

Comment: What gets logged when you try to log in to ProFTP as root with an incorrect password?

Comment: Do you *recognize* those keys? Are they the keys you (or authorized people) use to connect as root? As for the shell, if nothing special has been made to hide it, you will find it among the processes reported by `netstat -Welpt`, It will give you the PID, and you can use that to find it in /proc or in the ps output.

Comment: @LSerni According to `netstat -Welpt`, `apache2` `dovecot` `master` `mysqld` `psa-pc-remote` `rpcbind` `sshd` `sw-cp-server:` `xinetd` are running.

Comment: Have you actually set a root password on the box?

Comment: @schroeder afaik Ubuntu defaults to no root password and disabled login for root account. It *may* be that a blank password to proftpd may trigger this message as well...

Comment: @vidarlo "on the box"?

Answer (score 2):

## Good news. No unauthorized access seems to have happened.

**TL;DR this message appears whenever 'root' attempts a login, *even if they do not know the password and supply a wrong one*.**

It is important to distinguish **violations** (i.e. somebody broke in and entered your digital home) from **attempts** (i.e. somebody tried the door to see whether it was unlocked) and **recon** (i.e. somebody looked at your door to gauge how sturdy it looks).

Violations are, of course, emergencies.

Attempts are, up to a point, **normal** on today's Internet. Recons even more so. With so many sites having very easily guessable passwords, it is worthwhile to deploy automatic tools to trawl the Internet and hack into other machines - even if every single one gains very little in terms of computing resources or bandwidth firepower, at the end of the day evildoers stand a good chance of being in position to make some serious money.

So, logs of attempts are a dime a dozen. Just be sure to keep the system up-to-date and patched up, have backups *and* a disaster recovery plan ready and periodically checked/verified, keep passwords safe and practice safe computing -- and you'll be okay.

Many log scanners - not that I want to polemize against logwatch, aide, or so many other very useful tools! - have a tendency to overstate, if only by omission, the importance of the "threats" they "thwarted"/"detected".

When choosing between a tool that reports "20 of the usual, harmless attempts detected and ignored" and one that screams "Break-in attempt from IP1! Break-in attempt from IP2! Break-in attempt from IP3! OH MY GOD ANOTHER ONE! THEY'RE COMING OUT OF THE GODDAMN FIREWALLS!", nine users out of ten will choose the latter. So, you could say there's a certain evolutionary pressure that favors the screamers.

## research

I have researched the specific warning you received.

It comes from ProFTPD, in the module mod_auth, the source code can be found [here](https://github.com/proftpd/proftpd/blob/master/modules/mod_auth.c).

What interests us is this:

```
/* Next function (the biggie) handles all authentication, setting
 * up chroot() jail, etc.
*/
static int setup_env(pool *p, cmd_rec *cmd, const char *user, char *pass) {
```

The above means that the authentication function receives a character string called "pass". Apparently, the password supplied by the user is in there.

Let us see what happens when someone attempts a login: it is specified at line 1057:

```
unsigned char *root_allow = NULL;

pr_event_generate("mod_auth.root-login", NULL);

/* If RootLogin is set to true, we allow this... even though we
 * still log a warning. :)
 */
if ((root_allow = get_param_ptr(c ? c->subset : main_server->conf,
    "RootLogin", FALSE)) == NULL || *root_allow != TRUE) {
  if (pass) {
    pr_memscrub(pass, strlen(pass));
  }

  pr_log_auth(PR_LOG_NOTICE, "SECURITY VIOLATION: Root login attempted");
  return 0;
}
```

The above means that if the configuration parameter for `RootLogin`, with a default of FALSE, is NULL or, anyway, is not TRUE, then the warning is logged and the function returns early. The password is not even checked, it is destroyed, so this means that **there was no login**.

The comment in the code is **wrong**, because it says "we still log a warning". This is not true. For it to be true it should have been

```
pr_log_auth(PR_LOG_NOTICE, "SECURITY VIOLATION: Root login attempted");

if ((root_allow = get_param_ptr(c ? c->subset : main_server->conf,
    "RootLogin", FALSE)) == NULL || *root_allow != TRUE) {
  if (pass) {
    pr_memscrub(pass, strlen(pass));
  }
  return 0;
}
```

It might be that the comment refers to the line **above**: this is indeed executed always.

```
pr_event_generate("mod_auth.root-login", NULL);
```

The **actual login**, when the password is checked, happens later, beyond line 1200:

```
/* It is possible for the user to have already been authenticated during
 * the handling of the USER command, as by an RFC2228 mechanism.  If
 * that had happened, we won't need to call do_auth() here.
 */
if (authenticated_without_pass) {
  auth_code = PR_AUTH_OK_NO_PASS;
} else {
  auth_code = do_auth(p, c ? c->subset : main_server->conf, user_name, pass);
}
```

The lines above perform the authentication. Once the result is known, the password is destroyed:

```
pr_event_generate("mod_auth.authentication-code", &auth_code);

if (pass != NULL) {
  pr_memscrub(pass, strlen(pass));
}
```

...

```
switch (auth_code) {
  case PR_AUTH_OK_NO_PASS:
    auth_pass_resp_code = R_232;
    break;

  case PR_AUTH_OK:
    auth_pass_resp_code = R_230;
    break;

  case PR_AUTH_NOPWD:
    pr_log_auth(PR_LOG_NOTICE,
      "USER %s (Login failed): No such user found", user);
    goto auth_failure;
```

And to be even surer, this is the end of the function. In case of success it returns 1; upon failure it returns 0. Above, you saw that when that warning is issued, the function returns 0.

```
auth_failure:
  if (pass)
    pr_memscrub(pass, strlen(pass));
  session.user = session.group = NULL;
  session.gids = session.groups = NULL;
  session.wtmp_log = FALSE;
  return 0;
}
```

## Testing

I have installed the latest `proftpd`, 1.3.6c, available on a Ubuntu 20.04-LTS "Focal Fossa" VM. I have specified user `root` and a **wrong** password in my `.netrc` for that machine.
And lo and behold:

```
2020-09-28 23:44:21,829 vashnoi proftpd[2394977] vashnoi.local.vbox (vashnoi[192.168.2.200]): SECURITY VIOLATION: Root login attempted
```

(I also discovered I need to remove "proftpd-basic" instead of "proftpd", or it doesn't remove anything :-) )

Comment: So, if someone used the wrong password, the same message would appear?

Comment: @schroeder from the code, yes, absolutely. But I'm going to test this

Comment: So it actually means: "Someone tried to login with root as a username and some password, failed or succeeded and I assume he succeeded"

Comment: @PercivalJunghans the program doesn't assume that. But the documentation appears to say this, so you were justified in fearing the worst.

I can't understand; even the comment seems to suggest it. I can only think that the program DID log something if RootLogin was set to true, then this behaviour was changed but the comment was not updated.

CURRENTLY (and on the version I tried), that warning means only "You said root should not login, but someone tried". Which is quite normal, I have people trying to log as root on cleartext POP3. That's what happens when morons program crackbots.

Answer (score 0):

Detecting security events needs some previous steps as the logs concentration in a unique point.
Then, you can plug a SIEM onto this concentrator to match suspects pattern.

With a configuration like this, when an intruder get into your server, the logs are sent in real time to the concentrator. So, even if he can remove the local logs, you still have the duplicated ones on the concentrator.

Keep in mind, that "finding" an attacker is not as easy as knowing the IP address that get into your server. This IP address is probably just a relay. The attacker can be two, three or more IP jump away

Comment: The point is not "finding" him as in persecution, but finding the entry point and disabling it. But if you feel like it, you have his ip up there. Maybe you can find some weakness on his system.

Comment: There is no point at disabling an attacking IP if the attacker can change IP fast